# How to convert double[] to List<double[]> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a `Double[]` array that contains about 400k double values. I want to create a `List<Double[3]>` array out of it.

For example: we have a list of doubles `[0.00332, 1.23112, 0.241321, 2.0001 ...]`
We need to transform it into another structure like: `[[0.00332, 1.23112, 0.241321], [2.0001, ..., ...], [...]]`

I tried to come up with something but eventually understood that I have no idea how to do this in Java in more or less concise way. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Traverse your `double[]` and split it into three `double[]` arrays, then insert each resultant `double[]` in your `List<double[]>`.

Comment: Well that basically needs an algorithm and those are not dependent on any language. Can you think of one? We would be glad to help if you stumble meanwhile and show us your code.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "traverse"?

Comment: hmm, both mine and Barry's solution got instant down vote? Not sure why....

Comment: What's the logic of converting from one dimensional array to two dimensional?

Comment: [have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Maksym amplitudes of a wav file which we try to split into frames(subarray) of fixed length to apply, let's say, Hamming window function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<double[]> toListTuple(double [] array){
    List<double []> ret = new ArrayList<double[]>() ;

    double [] sublist = null;
    for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(sublist == null)
            sublist = new double[3];
        sublist[i%3] = array[i];
        if(i%3==2) {
            ret.add(sublist);
            sublist = null;
        }
    }

    if(sublist!=null){
        ret.add(sublist); // This means some of the last elements weren't initialized
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @StackFlowed you're wrong. Arrays are objects, so you can have `List<double[]>` with no problem.

Comment: @StackFlowed: source ?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas: your method does not return anything, though.

Comment: @StackFlowed - you do realise an array is an object in Java right? And that the generics type is just info for the compiler? Do you know any Java?

Comment: I didnt realize that the op wanted copy pastable code.

Comment: @DWolf I could post my code, but rather than correcting its bad logic isn't it better to see what ppl come up with?

Comment: I wasn't talking directly about you, im talking about all the other people being like "method doesn't return anything"  so what.. the logic is there.. im sure you could figure out the return if you wanted the code...

Answer (score 2):

```
double[] source = getValues();
List<Double[]> dest = new List<Double[]>;
for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i += 3)
{
    dest.add(new double[] {source[i], source[i + 1], source[i + 2]});
}
```

If you can guarantee that 3 | `source.length` .

Comment: hmm, this looks very nice, didn't know you can go away with the curly brackets like this. Thanks

Comment: @minerals be careful, read the note at the bottom: **If you can guarantee that 3 | `source.length`**.

Comment: oh, then it will not work for my case, my source.length is 400k -- one big double[] array

Comment: @minerals 3 | `source.length` means that "3 **divides** source.length", i.e. `source.length` is a multiple of 3. What would happen with the last few, anyway? accounting for that special case should be easy.

Comment: It just means the original array length needs to be a multiple of 3 or you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. You could also change the for loop test to "i < source.length - 2".

Answer (score 2):

There's various methods, this one will pad the last element in the array with zeroes if the original length isn't divisible by 3

```
List<double[]> list = new ArrayList<double[]>();
for (int i=0; i<original.length; i+=3) {
    list.add( Arrays.copyOfRange(original, i, i+3) );
}
```

Comment: wont that arrayindexoutofbounds when the original array isn't of length mod(3) == 0?  I think if you replace i+3 with a MAX function including length, its the most elegant solution though.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas No it won't throw, see [Arrays.copyOfRange()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28double[],%20int,%20int%29), it will if i > length, but it will use zeroes to fill the excess elements

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas it will only throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `0 > from` or `from > array.length`

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas and yes, using a `MAX` is obviously a good option if the length isn't known to be divisible by 3, though the OP asked to have a `List<double[3]>`, so I think in that case it better be always three elements.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas no you don't, since `i+3` is the `to`, not the `from`.

Comment: @outlyer Yeah, if it isn't going to error, then adding a MIN** doesn't answer the question as accurately.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Do'h, a MIN indeed :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
// Create a new list (in this example, an ArrayList) to hold the values
ArrayList<double[]> myList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
// Create a temporary subArray to hold the entries you'll store 
// on each entry of the list
double[] subArray;
// Traverse your original array (in this example: "myOriginalArray"
for(int i = 0; i < myOriginalArray.length; i++) {
    // If the entry of the original array is the first of each three,
    // initialize the temporary array
    if(i % 3 == 0) 
        subArray = new double[3];
    // Store the entry of the original array in the temp array
    subArray[i % 3] = myOriginalArray[i];
    // If the entry you've just stored is the last of each three
    // OR if the entry of the original array is the last one,
    // add the temporary array to your list
    if(i % 3 == 2 || i == myOriginalArray.length - 1)
        myList.add(subArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try Google Guava:

```
Double[] doubles = {3.0, 9.1, -1.1, 0.5};
List<List<Double>> doubleLists = Lists.partition(Arrays.asList(doubles), 3);
```

This will get you [[3.0, 9.1, -1.1], [0.5]]

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do it:

```
double[] values = ....
List<double[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 3) {
   double[] d = new double[3];
   d[0] = values[i];
   d[1] = values[i+1];
   d[2] = values[i+2];
   list.add(d);
}
```

Comment: True - or if the heap size is set too small to accomodate the List being created.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    double[] doubleArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
    ArrayList<double[]> doublelist = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    double[] innerArray = {};

    for(int i=0; i<doubleArray.length; i++){
        if(i%3 == 0){
            innerArray = new double[3];
        }
        innerArray[i%3] = doubleArray[i];
        if(i%3 == 2 || i == doubleArray.length-1){
            doublelist.add(innerArray);
        }
    }
}
```